# Creating Multi-Origin endpoint groups in Azure using Terraform

Tags: terraform, azure, terraform-module, cdn

I am attempting to provision multiple origins, which are storage accounts (blobs) in different regions. Whilst provisioning the CDN profiles (multiple environments) and a single origin for each is straightforward, the following error (which I assume is from Azure itself) is shown during "apply" the provisioning of multiple origins using a dynamic block. Note that "plan" runs without any issues.

> Error: creating Endpoint: (Name "cdn-endpoint-qa-ibkh" / Profile Name "cdn-qa-ibkh" / Resource Group "rg-cdns-ibkh"): cdn.EndpointsClient#Create: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="BadRequest" Message="In order to enable Multi-Origin on this endpoint, please set DefaultOriginGroup."
> │
> │   with module.content_cdns[1].azurerm_cdn_endpoint.default,
> │   on modules/azure_cdns/cdn.tf line 23, in resource "azurerm_cdn_endpoint" "default":
> │   23: resource "azurerm_cdn_endpoint" "default" {

The key section of the above is "In order to enable Multi-Origin on this endpoint, please set DefaultOriginGroup". I cannot find any documentation or examples about creating or setting the DefaultOriginGroup in Terraform.

Here is a copy of the code for the creation of multiple endpoints.

```
resource "azurerm_cdn_endpoint" "default" {
  name                          = var.cdn_endpoint_name
  profile_name                  = azurerm_cdn_profile.default.name
  location                      = "global"
  querystring_caching_behaviour = "IgnoreQueryString"
  is_http_allowed               = true
  is_compression_enabled        = false
  
  dynamic "origin" {
    for_each = var.azure_locations_cli
    content {
      name      = "${origin.value}-origin"
      host_name = "${replace(var.storage_account_name, "%%LOCATION%%", origin.value)}.blob.core.windows.net"
    }
  }
  
  tags = var.cdn_tags
  depends_on = [azurerm_cdn_profile.default]
  
}
```

I know that there is probably a workaround using local exec with Azure CLI, but I'd prefer not to use that unless there is no other option.

I am missing something blindingly obvious, or have I encountered something not yet fully supported by the Azure provider in Terraform?

Any advice or examples are greatly appreciated; thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not yet possible, since it requires an origin group. There is an open issue where you can vote though: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/10771.

Comment: Looks like there's no way of creating multiple cdn origins or default origin group in terraform. Here's the issue in github: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/10771